# Show how many elements every X time with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and I have an array like this

```
visits=["Wed, 01 Jan 2014 14:09:01 GMT","Wed, 01 Jan 2014 14:11:01 GMT","Wed, 01 Jan 2014 16:11:01 GMT"]
```

I want to make a graph which shows the how many people visited my website every hour. So In the example above, the graph would have two points, one point at 2 (because two visits within 1 hour, the first two elements) and another datapoint at 1.

I am not sure if there is any functionality to help me with this in highcharts. If there is, please let me know. If there isn't, any advice on creating the algorithm myself would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any ideas? Its harder than it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code.  Note, I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to do the date parsing.

```
var visits=["Wed, 01 Jan 2014 14:09:01 GMT","Wed, 01 Jan 2014 14:11:01 GMT","Wed, 01 Jan 2014 16:11:01 GMT"]

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < visits.length; i++){
    // create unique key of date/hour using momentjs
    var key = moment(visits[i]).format("YYYY, MMM DD, HH"); 
    // count them up
    if (key in counts){
        counts[key] += 1;   
    }else{
        counts[key] = 1;   
    }
}

// get data in correct format for highcharts
var cats = [];
var data = [];
for (var key in counts){
    cats.push(key);
    data.push(counts[key]);
}

// build chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis:{
        categories:  cats
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e2RQq/).

**EDITS FOR COMMENT**

To do ranges, I would switch to using timestamps as my unique key instead of a string.  With a little `Math.floor` you can bin into 10 second intervals.

```
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < visits.length; i++){
    // this key is the unix epoch to the nearest 10 second interval
    var key = Math.floor(moment(visits[i]).unix()/10)*10;
    if (key in counts){
        counts[key] += 1;   
    }else{
        counts[key] = 1;   
    }
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2RQq/1/).

Comment: Cool! Do you know if there is a way to get a specified time interval, like the amount of visits every 10 seconds rather than every hour, for example?